# How to add a custom tmLanguage syntax to Sphinx/RST

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, tmlanguage

Is there a method to import a `tmLanguage.json` into Sphinx to add support for a new/custom language for RST?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not directly; if necessary you'll have to write a lexer for a new language in Python. I say *if necessary* because Sphinx's syntax highlighting is provided under the hood by [Pygments](https://pygments.org), which supports a [huge number of languages](https://pygments.org/languages/); you just need to [turn support on](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#showing-code-examples) in Sphinx using the [`highlight_language`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-highlight_language) config value. The short names for all the various lexers are shown [here](https://pygments.org/docs/lexers).

If, somehow, your language doesn't have a lexer already, there are [instructions](https://pygments.org/docs/lexerdevelopment/) on how to write your own. It's largely (but not entirely) a process of translating the [Oniguruma regexes](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kkos/oniguruma/master/doc/RE) in the `.tmLanguage.json` file to [Python-flavored ones](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html).

One would also hope that you'd [contribute it](https://github.com/pygments/pygments/tree/master/pygments/lexers) to the `pygments` Github project, too.

Comment: I was hoping there might be some tools to convert a tmLang into python to save on dev time as there other things that have higher priority.
But a good list of links that will surely help in the future 